# listout all wi-fi SSID programmatically in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

1). I want to get all list of wi-fi SSID programmatically in iphone.

I try following code but it give only connected SSID detail.

```
NSArray *ifs = (id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
NSLog(@"%s: Supported interfaces: %@", __func__, ifs);
id info = nil;
for (NSString *ifnam in ifs) {
    info = (id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((CFStringRef)ifnam);
    NSLog(@"%s: %@ => %@", __func__, ifnam, info);
    if (info && [info count]) {
        break;
    }
    [info release];
}
```

2). Another question is that how can I identify that if I am come range in wi-fi when my wi-fi is OFF. Is it possible to identify that I am in range of wi-fi when wi-fi is OFF ?

Comment: 1. [Alljoyn](https://www.alljoyn.org/forums/developers/there-way-find-all-users-same-wifi-network-using-ios-version) and [On Google](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr#sclient=psy-ab&q=list+of+wi-fi+SSID+programatically+%2B+ios&oq=list+of+wi-fi+SSID+programatically+%2B+ios&gs_l=hp.3...331687.333104.1.333279.7.7.0.0.0.0.240.1327.2-6.6.0....0.0..1c.1j2.20.psy-ab.nl-EaCS_TvM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49478099%2Cd.bmk%2Cpv.xjs.s.en_US.c75bKy5EQ0A.O&fp=548a6aa251bed8a4&biw=1019&bih=625)
2. You can use [Reachability](https://github.com/belkevich/reachability-ios).

Answer (score 1):

1) You can only get details about your current network, such as SSID or BSSID, using the [CaptiveNetwork Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/index.html) that you're already using in your example. Apple doesn't allow developers to seek other networks in addition to the one the user is currently connected.

2) According to the [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) page, you can use that library to check if the user is currently connected via 3G or WiFi. You can't know if you are in range when Wi-Fi is set to Off.