# Can we scan Wi-Fi SSID to get their received signal sterngth (RSS) in iOS?

Tags: ios, wifi, wifimanager, indoor-positioning-system

I am searching for an answer to the above question for many days. Some related questions have been asked in StackOverflow, for example: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718967/listout-all-wi-fi-ssid-programatically-in-iphone)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451287/ios-11-0-periodically-scan-for-ssids-wifi-nearby). However, they suggest that it's not possible.

I want to use the RSS from Wi-Fi devices (access points) for indoor localization. It's quite easy with Android devices, where certain permission to access the Wi-Fi module is required. However, with iOS (iPhones), I couldn't find a way.

A published [journal](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8057286) has reported the indoor localization result using iPhone6 with Wi-Fi signals. But it doesn't say how did they do it. I had sent an email to the author of the paper, however, I couldn't get a reply.

Is there any way to access the Wi-Fi (scan the RSS of Wi-Fi devices) using iPhone? Has anybody done it?

If it's possible, a small hint or a small code snippet would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555640/how-to-get-wifi-ssid-in-ios9-after-captivenetwork-is-deprecated-and-calls-for-wi/31590787

Comment: I'm aware of [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555640/how-to-get-wifi-ssid-in-ios9-after-captivenetwork-is-deprecated-and-calls-for-wi/31590787). In fact, I had asked my question as a comment in the answers to that question.  However, I need to get permission from Apple and need to register my application as Hotspot helper. I write my iOS for research proposes only, not for commercial propose. Hence, the solution does not help me a lot.